# CollectionView Pull-to-Refresh Crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, collectionview

I have the following code for my pull-to-refresh "feature" (refreshing a CollectionView

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = UIRefreshControl.alloc.init;
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(startRefresh:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.collectionView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

However, this will crash my app with the following error message:

```
[CollectionViewController startRefresh:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7543610
2013-03-24 12:20:10.049 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CollectionViewController startRefresh:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7543610'
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: did you have a `startRefresh` method implemented?, if so, did this method takes an argument?

Comment: - (void) startRefresh:(UICollectionView *)startRefresh {
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

Comment: this "works" (as in "does not crash the app"), however, the indiciator will spin forever and it seems like no changes are made to the collection view.

Comment: you have to call `[refreshControl endRefreshing];` to stop the animation

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `startRefresh:` method takes an argument, that's what the colon in `@selector(startRefresh:)` means. The error that you are getting means that it cannot find the method and execute it.

To know what a selector is and the correct way to implement the target-action pattern, I recommend you to take a look at the docs, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I still wouldn't know how to fix it. i'm not too familiar with @selectors. can you elaborate some more? thank you.

Comment: thanks. i think this helped, but now i'm running into more problems. (as you can see above). quite sure, this is somewhat more tricky than an ios rookie like me can handle ;)